# Given $G = \{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6\}$, $M_0(1,-2,1)$ find $n$ (normal vector)

Tags: calculus

Given $G = \{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6\}$, $M_0(1,-2,1)$ **find** $n$ (normal vector)

In the solution it is written that $n = (F'_x(M_0),F'_y(M_0),F'_z(M_0)$

Which means $n = (2,-4,2)$. Can anyone explain why it is correct?

I know another way that works to get the normal of a sphere$(n = r'_u(u,v)\times r'_v(u,v)$).

But this one is quick. I'd like to understand why that works.

Comment: Compare to 2d version of sphere (i.e. circle), the normal vector should be co-linear with the $\lVert OM_0\rVert$

Comment: @ZackNi I didn't understand your answer. How comparing it with a circle will conclude that? and What is $O$? and will $M_0$ become $(1,-2)$?

Comment: O is the origin and $M_0$ is a point on the circle

Comment: @ZackNi So you've written me the formula of distance from $M_0$ to $(0,0)$ in 2d. (Gives me the length).

Comment: No just the vector. In the three dimensional case, n should be (1,-2,1)

Comment: the normal  vector n is the vector gradien of the implicite fonction $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ at the point $M_0$

Comment: @m.idaya but why

Comment: that is  gradient Property: the gradient vector of  implicit
function $f$ (for suitable $f$ that is differentiable) at a point
 of the graph of $f$ is normal to the tangent at this point
therefore is normal to the graph of $f$ at that point.